# Angular Directives - Knowing when the object bound to an attribute is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume that I have a scope that displays a list of Users on the left and detailed information about the currently selected user on the right.

I create a user details element directive with two way binding and end up with a directive object that looks something like this:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    user: "="
  },
  templateUrl: '...',
  controller: function() { ...elided...}
}
```

In the parent HTML, I use this directive as:

```
<user-details user="currentUser"></user-details>
```

As the user selection changes on the left, the currentUser property is updated, which causes the user property in the directive to point to a different object.  Angular handles re-rendering the HTML in the user-details directive well, but

*(Here's the question)*

Supposing that I have some small bit of work that I need to do when the displayed user is changed, perhaps a JSON string that should be parsed into an object.

How do I know that the bound object has changed (and that I need to re-parse)?

I have tried:

- Watching $scope.user
- Observing $attr, 'user'

The controller and link functions appear to only be called once.

Somewhere I must be missing something.  This doesn't seem like it should be that far off of the beaten path.

Comment: If you could be more specific about the problem it would be easier to help, but the best solution most likely involves more data bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use link and then watch the `user` like this:

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    user: "="
  },
  templateUrl: '...',
  link: function(scope) { 
    scope.$watch('user',function(value){
      // Do your stuff here
    });
  }
}
```

You could watch user with a function as well:

```
scope.$watch(function(){
  retrun scope.user;
}, function(value){
  // Do your stuff here
});
```

But then it would be updated only on digests. You can check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) or search as *angularjs digest cycle*.

**Edit:**

I forgot the `scope` argument since I just copy pasted.

Comment: The formatting was a little messed up, but that is one of the things that I tried.  It does not work.

Comment: Have you added the scope as an argument to the link function?

Comment: _But then it would be updated only on digests_ - What do you mean by that? The two versions are functionally equivalent.

Comment: scope.$watch() works, but you must watch the property by name.  E.g., scope.$watch('user', function(){}) not scope.$watch($scope.user, function(){}).  Thanks, this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You can either call `$apply` in the link function with `true` as the third parameter like this

```
scope.$watch('user', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log(newValue, oldValue);
}, true);
```

*This changes the "objectEquality" so that the user object will be compared for equality rather than for reference.*

or you can watch your user properties individually like this:

```
// suppose there is an user with age and gender properties:

scope.$watch('user.age', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});

scope.$watch('user.gender', function(newValue, oldValue) {
     console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});

// more properties to watch for ...
```

Comment: The key for me was watching the property by name.  Thank you for helping.